# Deserialization of a third party service reference in .net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, deserialization

I have 3 methods from a 3rd party service reference. Two of them work with my code i.e., I input the parameters to the service and I get the output back.

The third one works too if I use a direct URL to their server in SOAP UI tool I get the response.

The third method from my code gives me trouble. I input the param, it hits the service and I check the response in "Text Editor" of Visual studio and it shows the string output.

But somehow by the time I collect the response, it becomes null for strings and 0s for integers.

```
var test = myServiceClient.getMethodCValues(inputParam);
....

public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    myXMLResponse = reply.ToString();
}
```

The myXMLResponse above has the string formatted response in perfect format.All the properties with correct values (80 values/nodes). After this step/method, the debugging jumps to my var test line. Here test shows 80 nodes but all the properties are null/0s. Do let me know if you need more information to debug this.

Comment: How are the two snippets of code related?

Comment: The method in first line calls the getMethodCValues of the service. There is another class which implements IClientmessageInspector. One of the methods for that interface is AfterReceiveReply. When getmethodCValues is called it hits the service and on the way back  from the 3rd party,the last one it comes across is the method AfterReceiveReply(at least I think so). From here the debugger jumps to 'test' line. It is successful in getting the response like I said myXMLResponse is string and perfect. So if anyone worked on such scenario they can help me out.

Comment: It may be worth including complete code in your question...

Comment: Dang!.Well, as it turns out 3rd party did NOT put their updated code out. #facepalm. So I tried with their latest one,I deleted the service reference and added it again and it worked like a charm. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: It was worth it to hear you say Dang.